# Override MacOS Terminal Menu With Embedded Dash

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app, system-preferences

I see a menu item in MacOS Terminal which looks like "New Tab with Profile - Homebrew".  I'd like to override the Cmd-T shortcut which Terminal helpfully assigned to it because the last tab I opened was a Homebrew tab.

For most shortcut keys, I'd follow the process helpfully defined at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214191/shortcut-key-to-open-apply-profile-in-terminal

I can override a shortcut to most Terminal menus (e.g. "Close Tab" or "Close Window"), but when I try to override "New Tab with Profile - Homebrew" it doesn't work.

The obvious answer is that the "-" must not be a plain old hyphen.  I tried en dash, em dash, typographic minus sign, and several other dash-like characters but none worked.

1. How do I override "New Tab with Profile - Homebrew"?
2. Is there a way I can discover for myself the exact text in a menu which is dynamically generated (as this one is)?

Comment: Is it just my imagination or is the 'dash' in New Window with profile different to the one in New Tab with Profile? I can confirm it works if I use just 'New Tab' but I can't figure out what that dash is either. Quick & dirty bit of photoshopping - they are indeed different https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9tGr.png

Comment: Interestingly, I can't get 'New Tab with Same Command' to work either, whether directed using -> or simple. To prove to myself I am getting the syntax right I added a command to Basic too, which does work… https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRTcc.png

Comment: It looks like none of the items above the line can be modified.  I'm guessing that because both New Window with profile and New Tab with profile are dynamically generated, *that* is what makes them non-overerideable.